# Firebase -- Bulk delete child nodes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am building a simple todo app using reactFire, Firebase, and reactJS. The problem I am running into is when I try to bulk delete completed entries in the list.

```
componentWillMount: function() {
        this.ref = Firebase.database().ref("items/");
        this.bindAsArray(this.ref, "items");
        this.ref.on('value', this.handleDataLoaded);
}

for (var i in this.state.items) {
            var key = items[i]['.key'];
            if(items[i].done){
                this.ref.child(key).remove();
            }
}
```

The loop ends prematurely i.e. before deleting all the completed entries, because the render function is called.

Comment: `done` is a bollean value inside the item branch right?

Comment: what version of firebase are you running? I'm asking because react-fire doesn't support the latest changes to FB API.

Comment: @adolfosrs yes it is @U r s u s, I am using firebase 3.0.5 and reactfire 1.0.0

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can delete all completed items in one go by using a multi-location update:

```
var updates = {};
for (var i in this.state.items) {
    var key = items[i]['.key'];
    if(items[i].done){
        updates[key] = null; // setting value to null deletes the key
    }
}
this.ref.update(updates);
```

Comment: "// setting value to null deletes the key." That's what I needed, thanks!

Comment: If setting the value to `null` deletes the key, how can you update a key to a null value?

Comment: @Crashalot `null` is an invalid key