# how to chain multiple promises into a single transaction in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

A few months back Firebase implemented [promises in the database](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/01/keeping-our-promises-and-callbacks_76.html).

In that blog post there is an example of using a single transaction with promises:

```
var article;
var articleRef = ref.child('blogposts').child(id);
articleRef.once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
  article = snapshot.val();
  return articleRef.child('readCount').transaction(function(current) {
    return (current || 0) + 1;
  });
}).then(function(readCountTxn) {
  renderBlog({
    article: article,
    readCount: readCountTxn.snapshot.val()
  });
}, function(error) {
  console.error(error);
});
```

Is it possible to chain multiple promises into a single transaction to be able to erase data only if everything can be erased?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you actually need a transaction or just an atomic operation? You can execute atomic operations on multiple paths simultaneously that will fail if something goes wrong with one of them (ie erase which is a write operation):

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com");

var updatedUserData = {};
updatedUserData["user/posts/location1"] = null;
updatedUserData["user/blogs/location2"] = null;
// Do a deep-path update
ref.update(updatedUserData).then(function() {
    //yay
}, function(error) {
    console.log("Error updating data:", error);
});
```

**Transactions** on the other hand are typically used for atomic data modifications where concurrent updates could cause an inconsistent data state. Imagine an upvote counter:

```
// user 1
upvotesRef.transaction(function (current_value) {
  return (current_value || 0) + 1;
});
// user 2
upvotesRef.transaction(function (current_value) {
  return (current_value || 0) + 1;
});

// upvotesRef will eventually be consistent with value += 2
```

Without transactions, you are not guaranteed this consistency:

```
// user 1
ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val()); // oops, could be the same value as user 2!
  ref.set(snapshot.val() + 1);
});
// user 2
ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val()); // oops, could be the same value as user 1!
  ref.set(snapshot.val() + 1);
});
```

More info [here](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/09/introducing-multi-location-updates-and_86.html)

Comment: Oh that's clever, I didn't you could also "delete" that way.

Comment: Today I learned that Pier doesn't read all my answers. :-(
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38084531/firebase-bulk-delete-child-nodes/38084832#38084832   ;-)

Comment: Great answer btw tommy. Not simply answering the question, but solving the use-case in a much simpler way. Nice!

Comment: Thanks Frank! If you need an intern this fall don't hesitate to reach out ;)