# How to treat multiple writes so that if one write fails, the data isn't committed?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In **Firebase Realtime Database**, let's say that I need to add a `child_node1` to `node1` and, immediately after that, a `child_node2` to `node2`, the information being related.

I could easily add the second child node in the completion handler of the insertion of the first child node. But what if the user closes the app exactly during the second call? Or the network suddenly goes down?

How should I make sure that the information gets committed if and only if both calls (transactions) succeed?

**For example**, after creating a user in the main node (`users`), I want to also add him in another node called `users-locations` according to his location. What if an error occurs after adding in `users` but before finishing adding in `users-locations`?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you read about transactions in Realtime Database? https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions

Comment: @DougStevenson Yes, but as far as I understand, they are for the purpose of handling conccurent writes on the same data. In my case, I want to add the nodes in different locations. Could you please further explain me how I should use them to solve my problem? Thanks!

Comment: Transactions will do both (you said "transaction", so I went there first).  If you just want to write to two different locations at the same time, do a multi-location update.  The blog is old, but the info is still relevant: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/09/introducing-multi-location-updates-and_86.html

Comment: @DougStevenson The multi-location update is just what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do is a fan-out operation, and as Doug commented you'll typically want to do this with a single multi-location update. Multi-location updates scale **much** better than transactions.

For example, to write to both locations at once you'd do:

```
let updates = ["/node1/child_node1": "value", "/node2/child_node2": "value"]

ref.updateChildValues(updates)
```

Some great sources for reading more about these are:

- the [blog post introducing multi-location updates](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/09/introducing-multi-location-updates-and_86.html)
- the [blog post discussing using multi-location updates for fan-out operations](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/10/client-side-fan-out-for-data-consistency_73.html)
- my answer on [strategies for data consistency with denormalized data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30693785/how-to-write-denormalized-data-in-firebase)
- Andrew's [answer on a similar topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17437695/firebase-how-do-i-update-multiple-resources-atomically/17438028#17438028)
- an [answer showing how to do multi-location deletes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42151186/how-to-make-consistent-delete-in-firebase-database-when-the-data-lies-in-multipl/42151855#42151855)
- many other [questions mentioning multi-location updates](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bfirebase%5d%20multi-location%20update)

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thanks a lot!