# Firebase - atomic write of multiple values to multiple locations

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

I need to register an object to Firebase. The object has multiple fields, and I need to write them all to multiple paths.

My code :

```
public func RegisterProductOnDatabase(database dataBase: DatabaseReference)
{
    // Run in one transaction
    RegisterProductOnDatabase(database: dataBase)
    RegisterProductForAllUsers(database: dataBase)
}

private func RegisterProductForAllUsers(database dataBase: DatabaseReference)
{
    dataBase.child("Products").child(self.UniqueID()).child("Name").setValue(self.Name())
    dataBase.child("Products").child(self.UniqueID()).child("UniqueID").setValue(self.UniqueID())
    dataBase.child("Products").child(self.UniqueID()).child("Price").setValue(self.Price())
    dataBase.child("Products").child(self.UniqueID()).child("Description").setValue(self.Description())
    dataBase.child("Products").child(self.UniqueID()).child("ToBuy?").setValue(self.m_ToBuy)
    dataBase.child("Products").child(self.UniqueID()).child("ToSell?").setValue(self.m_ToSell)
    dataBase.child("Products").child(self.UniqueID()).child("Owner").setValue(self.m_Owner)
    dataBase.child("Products").child(self.UniqueID()).child("Amount").setValue(self.m_Amount)
    dataBase.child("Products").child(self.UniqueID()).child("MainImage").setValue(self.m_PicturesURLs.first)
}

private func RegisterProductForAddingUser(database dataBase: DatabaseReference)
{        
    dataBase.child("Users").child(m_Owner).child("Products").child(self.UniqueID()).child("Name").setValue(self.Name())
    dataBase.child("Users").child(m_Owner).child("Products").child(self.UniqueID()).child("UniqueID").setValue(self.UniqueID())
    dataBase.child("Users").child(m_Owner).child("Products").child(self.UniqueID()).child("Price").setValue(self.Price())
    dataBase.child("Users").child(m_Owner).child("Products").child(self.UniqueID()).child("Description").setValue(self.Description())
    dataBase.child("Users").child(m_Owner).child("Products").child(self.UniqueID()).child("ToBuy?").setValue(self.m_ToBuy)
    dataBase.child("Users").child(m_Owner).child("Products").child(self.UniqueID()).child("ToSell?").setValue(self.m_ToSell)
    dataBase.child("Users").child(m_Owner).child("Products").child(self.UniqueID()).child("Amount").setValue(self.m_Amount)
    dataBase.child("Users").child(m_Owner).child("Products").child(self.UniqueID()).child("MainImage").setValue(self.m_PicturesURLs.first)
}
```

I need the function "RegisterProductOnDatabase" to run as one transaction - meaning all written values to be written as one transaction.

1) How can I write all this data as ONE transaction using Swift ?
2) Is there a better way to write all these values without code multiplication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you should use dictionaries instead of manually modifying each node.

This is from the Firebase documentation:

```
let key = ref.child("posts").childByAutoId().key
let post = ["uid": userID,
            "author": username,
            "title": title,
            "body": body]
let childUpdates = ["/posts/\(key)": post,
                    "/user-posts/\(userID)/\(key)/": post]
ref.updateChildValues(childUpdates)
```

Read more about writing data [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#basic_write).

Secondly, in order to modify in multiple locations, use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48838146/3185860) answer as I have recently had the same question.

Comment: I'm having some trouble understanding this. In my case, this code should 

be : let key = ref.child("Products").child(Product.UniqueID).key
let prod = [ // all fields here]
let childUpdates = ["/Products/\(key)" : prod, "users/(UserID)/\(key)/": prod]
ref.updateCHildValues(childUpdates)

Comment: So this works for UPDATING, is it the same for WRITING ?

Comment: Update works the same as writing. If the node isn't there, it will create it. Please read the first link I referenced.