# Remove multiple children inside a key using Firebase and React Native

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

The code below works as intended when removing just one child, however I need to remove multiple children, in my case 6. See attached screenshot. How would I go about adding all 6 children to the remove function?

```
deleteActivity= () => {
    const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();
    firebase
      .database()
      .ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}/data/${this.state.dateForFirebase}`)
      .remove('ActivityStart1');      
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you could pass an object with the keys to remove seted to null through an atomic update.

try this and let me know if it works

```
deleteActivity= () => {
    const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();
    const ref = firebase.database().ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}/data/${this.state.dateForFirebase}`)
    var atomicUpdate = {};
    atomicUpdate["ActivityAvgHR1/"] = null;
    atomicUpdate["ActivityCalories/"] = null;
    atomicUpdate["ActivityDurationHrs1/"] = null;
    atomicUpdate["ActivityDurationMns1/"] = null;
    atomicUpdate["ActivityMaxHR1/"] = null;
    atomicUpdate["ActivityStart1/"] = null;

    ref.update(atomicUpdate)

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#delete_data):

> Delete data The simplest way to delete data is to call remove() on a reference to the location of that data.
>
> You can also delete by specifying null as the value for another write
>   operation such as set() or update(). You can use this technique with
>   update() to **delete multiple children** in a single API call.

Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42151186/how-to-make-consistent-delete-in-firebase-database-when-the-data-lies-in-multipl) and update the paths with null values.