# Batch Deletes with Firebase Python Admin SDK

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

The Firebase Python Admin SDK has a bulk [`update()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.db#query) method, but you can't use it the same as the bulk deletes in the Javascript Admin SDK, since you cannot have `None` dict values (SDK [validation](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-python/blob/cd4e7d694ba31e326ce6242b82b4b5a40ec7e37c/firebase_admin/db.py#L272)).

The SDK docs are sparse and there are next to no available examples. Does anyone know how to batch deletes in Python?

[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38084832/564157) of bulk delete in Javascript:

```
const parentRef = db.reference('parent/foo/')
const children = parentRef.get()
const updates = {};

Object.keys(children).forEach( childKey => {

  const childEntry = children(childKey)
  if( shouldDelete(childEntry) ) {
    updates[childKey] = null; // setting value to null deletes the key
  }
}
parentRef.update(updates);
```

Comment: Did you manage to get Python SDK to work? I've already have a script developed in Python but got hit with the SDK validation. Bad part is that I got this error at the last step before "production" use. Should I migrate my script to Node SDK?

Comment: Looked at the code and skipped over the validation using the internal methods of db.Reference.  `db_ref._client.request('patch', db_ref._add_suffix(), json=update_statement)`